# Display/use data received from C# using "POST" method in PHP

Tags: c#, php, post

I want to post data from C#(Windows Forms Application) to PHP using $_POST, but getting empty value when checking with echo/var_dump, while in Locals windows of VS, showing the value of ResponseStream with data that has been posted. I don't know if the problem is in C# method or PHP script or anything else.

From [Pass data from C# to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227604/pass-data-from-c-sharp-to-php), and some more questions, in my case, I have applied it as the following.

PHP script (post.php):

```
<?php

// *** Use $_GET, the echo works when testing parameters from browser's address bar, but GET method in C# will fail. 

//if(isset($_POST['data'])){
//if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  $data = $_POST['data'];
  echo "Hello, ";
  echo $data;
//}

?>

<!-- for debug purpose -->
<pre>
<?php 
var_dump($_POST); 
//print_r($_POST);

var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
</pre>
```

C# method:

```
public string SendPost(string url, string postData)
{
    string webpageContent = string.Empty;

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)(0x30 | 0xc0 | 0x300 | 0xc00);    

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506575/how-to-ignore-the-certificate-check-when-ssl
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        delegate (object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true; // **** Always accept
    };


    try
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        using (Stream webpageStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            webpageStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                webpageContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {        
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Data has been posted.");
    return webpageContent;
}
```

Here is how I call method:

```
String pData = "TestString";
SendPost("https://websites/post.php", String.Format("data={0}", pData));
```

---

**Results**

In Locals windows, the return value of "webpageContent":

```
Hello, TestString
```

From browser, "https://websites/post.php":

```
Hello,
```

How to keep/display/use the value received from C# in PHP?